# ASP UserControl with delete and edit buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on ASP.NET web application and I encountered a problem.

I have a database with table 'sticky' which consists of attributes 'id' and 'text'.
I made a UserControl and named it 'StickyControl'.
StickyControl contains Label to show some text, Button to edit sticky and Button to delete sticky.
I want to delete sticky on delete Button click.

On PageLoad method I load all stickies from database and it works.
Also, delete Button from StickyControl works.

Now what is the problem?
When I click delete button:
1.PageLoad is run and all StickyControls are dynamically added to the screen. 
2.My code from delete Button is run (because of page lifcycle,even handlers are run after PageLoad) 
So I end up with wrong information on the screen. I have to click two times actually.

How can I avoid that? Is there a 'correct' way of implementing this?

When I click Button 'Obriši', sticky must be removed from the screen.
[image]

```
//This is PageLoad method from page where I show stickies
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Current user id
            String id= Request.QueryString["id"]; 

            // Get stickies from current user
            List<Sticky> stickies = Database.getStickies(id); 

            // Load stickies to screen
            foreach(Sticky s in stickies)
            {
               StickyControl stickyControl = (StickyControl)LoadControl("StickyControl.ascx");
               stickyControl.Text= s.Text;
               stickyControl.Id = s.Id;
               panelStickies.Controls.Add(stickyControl);
            }
        }



//This is delete button in StickyControl.ascx
      protected void btnDeleteSticky_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          Database.deleteSticky(Id);           
       }
```

Comment: You can start by only loading  when the page.isPostback. that way it doesn't reload when you click a button. If you would like additional assistance, please show the code you are trying.

Comment: In that case it wont reload stickies and deleted sticky will be visible on the screen. I updated my question with some code

Answer (score 0):

I would arrange it something like this so that when delete is pressed, you do not reload before the delete function is run, then you can call it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {
        LoadStickies();
    }
}

private void LoadStickies() 
{
    // Current user id
    String id= Request.QueryString["id"]; 

    // Get stickies from current user
    List<Sticky> stickies = Database.getStickies(id); 

    // Load stickies to screen
    foreach(Sticky s in stickies)
    {
        StickyControl stickyControl = (StickyControl)LoadControl("StickyControl.ascx");
        stickyControl.Text= s.Text;
        stickyControl.Id = s.Id;
        panelStickies.Controls.Add(stickyControl);
    }    
}

protected void btnDeleteSticky_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Database.deleteSticky(Id);   
    LoadStickies();        
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The reason it does not work is because of event handlers of my StickyControl. In case IsPostBack is true LoadStickies() is called after Page Loading but event handlers must be attached before Page Loading is completed.